# Mosquitto broker service not starting on Windows

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I installed mosquitto for Windows, and ran the following command from command prompt as administrator:

`net start mosquitto`

I get the following message:

> The Mosquitto Broker service is starting. The Mosquitto Broker service
> could not be started.
>
> The service did not report an error.

What could be the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When running Mosquitto Broker as a service on Windows, it will always look for a config file in the `MOSQUITTO_DIR` path.

If you do not have a config file there, it will fail. Usually the installer creates this for you, I suggest you to check if the configuration file is present.

Comment: I edited the config so it was not recognizing it. Its working now. thanks

Comment: Here the source for official installer on line 87 it set MOSQUITTO_DIR https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/installer/mosquitto64.nsi#L87